# How to retrieve only (not all) particular elements from XML using XStream (for an Android Web service)?

Tags: android, xml, xstream

What is the best way to parse an XML file from a Web Service from a third-party in Android ?

It seems that with XStream, I need to define classes and attributes for everything in the XML. But I only want to use like 5% of the XML, is there a shorcut for this in XStream?

```
# Space.java
public class Space {
    String id = null;
    String name = null;
}

# Parsing Code
        XStream xs = new XStream(new XppDomDriver());
        xs.alias("space", Space.class);
        Space s = (Space) xs.fromXML( myXMLData );

# space.xml
<space>
  <can-join type="boolean">false</can-join>
  <created-at type="datetime">2011-05-04T16:12:27-04:00</created-at>
  <default-showpage>Source/SVN</default-showpage>
  <description>Assembla Time Tracker for Android</description>
  <id>dvpLtiDOOr4lSCeJe5cbCb</id>
  <is-commercial type="boolean">true</is-commercial>
  <is-manager type="boolean">true</is-manager>
  <is-volunteer type="boolean">false</is-volunteer>
  <name>Assemblandroid TimeTracker</name>
  <parent-id nil="true"></parent-id>
  <public-permissions type="integer">0</public-permissions>
  <team-permissions type="integer">2</team-permissions>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2011-05-04T16:12:27-04:00</updated-at>
  <watcher-permissions type="integer">1</watcher-permissions>
  <wiki-name>assemblandroid-timetracker</wiki-name>
</space>
```

Comment: Right now, I've switched to using Xpath which works pretty well if targetting android 2.2 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SAXParser` and `DefaultHandler` classes.

Comment: I've  looked at SAX, but it drives me insane to have to write more code than the size of the xml.

Comment: @David:  i didn't find i had to write to much code.  i guess if you control the format of the xml you could take certain things for granted, such as the order the elements appear in, so you wouldn't need as much conditional checking.  i don't know what licensing issues you may have using a third party library, that would be my concern on a paid for app.  all the best.